# undefined reference to `kecil' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status in C

Tags: c

how to fix the error messege ??
this is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    void kapital (char *);
    void kecil (char *);

    void main ()
    {
        char kata[100];

        printf("Masukkan Sebuah stirng: : ");
        gets(kata);

        printf("jumlah karakter kapital dari string tersebut : ");
        kapital(kata);

        printf("\n");
        
        printf("Jumlah Karakter huruf kecil dari string tersebut : ");
        kecil(kata);
    }

    void kapital (char (*p))

    {
        int kapital = 0;
        while (*p)
        {
            if (isupper(*p))
            {
                kapital++;
            }
            *p++;
        }
        printf(" %d", kapital);
    }
```

i tried to fix the symbols but , it's still not worked this code is my lesson for my collage , but idk how to fix i tried what i can but still not worked , please help me!!!

Comment: Do you know where `kecil` is implemented/defined? You need to link in the object or library that contains that. We can't tell you that as we don't know your code base. Or perhaps you are required to implement that yourself. There is not enough context and info for us to say much more than that.

Comment: @Andi Yusdar Al Imran What is unclear with the error message?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact command you use to build your preogram. The code shown in the question does not contain a *definition* of a function `kecil`, it only contains a *prototype* (*declaration*). So the compiler expects the function to be defined somewhere else. You wrote "i tried to fix the symbols" and "i tried what i can". Please show what you tried.

Comment: If you would translate everything to English chances would increase that somebody can guess where the kecil() is defined. My gut feeling says you should have written the code for the function and placed it next to `kapital()`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main ()`  there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  They are: `int main( void)` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Your compiler should have told you about this problem

Comment: OT: regarding: `gets(kata);`  The function `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely eliminated around 2009.   Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  Suggest using `fgets()`  (which has a different parameter list)

Answer (score 0):

the function: `void kecil (char *);` is missing from the posted code.

Suggest you write that function, which will eliminate the linker error message